# NameError: name 'setSaldo' is not defined

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou aprendendo POO em python e estou tendo um problema. Quando eu tento usar os getters e setters não estou conseguindo.

```
#Método Construtor
def __init__(self):
    self.saldo = 0
    self.status = False

#Métodos Especiais
def getSaldo(self):
    return self.saldo
def setDono(self, d):
    self.dono = d

    #Demais Métodos
def abrirConta(self):
    if self.status == False:
        a = input('Quem é o titular da conta? ')
        setDono(a)
        self.tipo = input('Qual é o tipo da conta? ')
        self.status = True
        if self.tipo == 'CC':
            self.saldo = 50
            print('Parabéns, sua conta corrente está aberta. Você já tem 50 reais de saldo.')
        elif self.tipo == 'CP':
            self.saldo = 150
            print('Parabéns, sua conta poupança está aberta. Você já tem 150 reais de saldo.')
```

Quando eu chamo o setter `setDono` no mesmo documento da classe ele me dá erro, dizendo que `setDono` não está definido. Caso eu chame ele em outro documento, como em um objeto instanciado ele funciona, porém os getters retornam o que me parece ser a localização na memória que o dado está alocado, ao invés do que ele contém

Comment: Este erro acontece pelo fato de tua classe não possuir este atributo dono definido. Experimente colocar no construtor igualmente ao atributo **saldo** e **status**.

Comment: Fiz isso, coloquei no construtor self.dono e ele continua a repetir o erro. Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Qual a linha que emitiu o erro? Poste ela e poste o `def` setSaldo também. Confira se tem algum "decorador" no setSaldo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para chamar o método/função `setDono()` você precisa especificar que está chamando o método da própria classe, dessa forma fazendo `self.setDono()`.
Além disso, recomendo que quando for criar os atributos no construtor, insira um `underscore` no início do nome do atributo indicando que ele é um atributo privado da classe (é uma convenção adotada) assim como eu fiz.

```
class Conta:

    def __init__(self):
        self._saldo = 0
        self._status = False
        self._dono = ""

    #Métodos Especiais
    def getSaldo(self):
        return self._saldo
    def setDono(self, d):
        self._dono = d

        #Demais Métodos
    def abrirConta(self):
        if self._status == False:
            a = input('Quem é o titular da conta? ')
            self.setDono(a)
            self.tipo = input('Qual é o tipo da conta? ')
            self._status = True
            if self.tipo == 'CC':
                self._saldo = 50
                print('Parabéns, sua conta corrente está aberta. Você já tem 50 reais de saldo.')
            elif self.tipo == 'CP':
                self._saldo = 150
                print('Parabéns, sua conta poupança está aberta. Você já tem 150 reais de saldo.')
```

Comment: SIm, eu não coloquei o código todo na postagem pra não ficar muito grande, mas indiquei sim que é uma classe.

Comment: Seguinte, o problema do `setDono()` não estar sendo mostrado é que para chama-lo você deve fazer `self.setDono()` assim como eu coloquei na minha resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Isso que eu não estava entendendo!

Comment: @Ferrugem, Se deu tudo certo e seu problema foi resolvido, marque por favor a resposta como correta para que outros que tenham o mesmo problema que você vejam e possam solucionar o mesmo problema